# How much information should be included in a Saved list's item?

Tags: lists, save, information

When showcasing products in a gallery, we display a bunch of information in each product cell. Those infos include:

- Picture
- Full name
- Rating (stars) & number of user ratings
- product comparison button
- Price and number of parcels
- Save product button

Plus, if the item meets the conditions:

- "Good Deal" label
- Featured label
- editor's pick

Yes, it's **a lot**. They all can be on a product at the same time.

My question is: once the user saved the item, what should be displayed on his list?

It seems to me that the item should only use what's most relevant in that context and it should be considered that the user has once made a conscious choice to save that specific product, therefore he doesn't need information that's supposed to make it more attractive among similar ones.

That said, what should be the approach here? a slimmed down version of the product cell, without as much info? What is not absolutely necessary here?

Comment: I would like to ask what is the scenario? It is kinda unclear to me and I believe based on the scenario, I can recommend a solution :) thanks.

Comment: @aliesifar, think of it as a wishlist type of thing. The user saves the product from a gallery to his or her profile.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, since the user made a conscious decision to add the product in the wishlist, an image card can be a good thing to be shown as the main object, then try to the title of the product on that, but it is not that important, so if the text is tool long use "..." to just fit that in one line on top of the image card. For the last 3 items ("Good Deal" label, Featured label, editor's pick) use 3 clear icons, then in case if each of them were applying on a product, you only need to show those icons  in a top corner over the image card (like top-left, which is an active corner). A hover action in this case is required to be don on each icon to make sure that the user gets the meaning of that icon. For rating show stars and maybe number of reviews in parenthesis next to those stars, and put that under neath of the title. Then in the button of your card write "Compare" and make it link, put that in the left, and write "+Add" and put that in the right- down corner (Which is another active corner in the card). For prices and number of parcels, use a 75% transparent on top of the title, and with white color you can represent the price, that black transparent box can be either small or big, to me it is kinda dependent to your sales strategy, I would recommend using a small boxes.

All of them are suggestions for this special scenario that you mentioned, I was trying to use your corners appropriately and define a priority, you absolutely have a better insight about your product and users, that will help you to adjust this suggestion.

I hope it helps.

Comment: So in your opinion all the info on the gallery item should be reflected on the list item?

Comment: If you want so, that would be one of the good cases to show all the information that you mentioned. Otherwise, I would personally show these: Picture, Full name (in case if it fits in a line), product comparison button, Price and number of parcels, Save product button. I would still recommend the style that I mentioned. In case if it is a "Good Deal" option, I think probably that would be important to be notified in that list, and I would hesitate to use the other two items (Featured label and editor's pick).

Comment: I believe you should have usability test in both cases, then see how your users feel and react about that, because it is too much related to the specific context and product types that you have.

Comment: At this point, the product is already saved. My question pertains what information is indispensable on this list, because I feel it doesn't need as much as on the rest of the site.

Comment: Yeah, I got that and that's why in my comment I suggested the important one. Instead of save button you can use the "+Add button" to have that in the check out. I would again recommend to have 3,4 different set up of these information, and do the user testing on those.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this are items for sale, so, what does it mean a lot? You want to make a sale, and you should not save efforts in doing so. Plus, any info that helps you close the sale is always useful. Plus, based in your description, I think you don't have a lot of info, but you have some "noise".

First of all: assuming these are items for sale as mentioned above, I can see 2 common paths:

## 1. Save for "later purchase"

you're saving items for "later purchase" and not as part of a checkout flow. If this is the case, I'd recommend to try to *"close the deal"* ASAP and stop worrying about providing **"traffic leaks"**. But if you want to follow this path anyways, there are some things you can consider:

- from your description, you're leaving out the most important part: the *call to action* or **CTA**
- as you mention, the user has gone through a selection process, thus he knows some info. So, you only need photo, name, price and some selling points if you wish, like the editor pick, featured, whatever. Note that I left out the COMPARE button. I strongly recommend you to test this, but in general, I avoid users to compare things as much as possible in order to avoid distractions. Your decision, of course, but if you feel like adding more options to the process, try related products (like "users who bought **product 1** also bought **product 2**")
- as I mentioned you don't have a lot of info, as a matter of fact it's pretty restricted. In general, we (I mean my studio) consider A LOT of info anything that can't be added in a clean way in a small phone screen. So I took your info and did this quick mock:

[image]

(the 3 circles on top are supposed to be icons for your additional conditions)

See how they fit in a single screen, and as a matter of fact there's still a lot of place. So let's shrink it even more:

[image]

See? You don't have a lot of info. And keep in mind I have added a HUGE call to action!

## 2. Save as part of a checkout process

Here, it's even easier. Just add the picture, name and price. Everything else is *noise* and absolutely not needed

## 3. Save as catalog or collection

This is an additional option that could happen if you aren't actually selling, but creating user-driven catalogs. In this case, you may consider the same approach as 1, only that instead of "buy" you should change to "add to catalog" or something like that. This is an unlikely scenario, but since I don't know your real scenario, it's worth mentioning.

## IN SHORT

Be very careful in adding more friction to a sales process. Any additional link or distraction will affect your sales volume, sometimes to massive extents. Keep things clean and direct. If you want to sell, just **SELL**, drive the user to the desired end by following logical paths and avoid unnecessary decorations or info that will derail the user for the chosen path

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Devin. As every product has multiple sellers, the user must me directed to the full product page before purchase anyway. I think it fits best in your third option. What I guess I'm trying to do is much like what you suggested, slim down the product info and lessen the friction. That said, I really like the idea of adding a call to action to it, maybe even rearrange items on clearance to help drive sales.